# Trouble building Boost Log example using Bazel

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, boost, bazel

I am using Bazel as my build system and have had no problems with Boost up until I started trying to use Boost Log, I was even able to use some of the compiled libraries without issue however when tried to use Boost.Log or tried to build the example for trivial logging I get a host of undefined reference errors.

I have tried building with the following bazel build commands:

`bazel build //app:boost-log-test`

`bazel build --cxxopt="-pthread" //app:boost-log-test`

`bazel build --cxxopt="-lpthread" //app:boost-log-test`

`bazel build --cxxopt="-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK" --cxxopt="-lpthread" //app:boost-log-test`

`bazel build --cxxopt="-lboost_log" --cxxopt="-lpthread" //app:boost-log-test`

`bazel build --cxxopt="-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK" --cxxopt="-lboost_log" //app:boost-log-test`

`bazel build --cxxopt="-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK" --cxxopt="-lboost_log" --cxxopt="-lpthread" //app:boost-log-test`

`bazel build --cxxopt="-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK" --cxxopt="-lboost_log" --cxxopt="-lpthread" --cxxopt="-std=c++17" //app:boost-log-test`

and all resulted in the same errors which I've included at the bottom of this post. My Boost root is located at `/opt/boost/boost_1_77_0` and below is my project structure.

`./WORKSPACE`:

```cxx
new_local_repository(
    name = "boost",
    path = "/opt/boost/boost_1_77_0",
    build_file = "external/boost.BUILD",
)
```

`./external/boost.BUILD`:

```cxx
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "boost-headers",
    hdrs = glob(["include/boost/**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    includes = ['include'],
)

cc_library(
    name = "boost-allbuilt",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.a"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

...

cc_library(
    name = "boost-log",
    srcs = ["lib/libboost_log.a"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "boost-log_setup",
    srcs = ["lib/libboost_log_setup.a"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

...

cc_library(
    name = "boost-wserialization",
    srcs = ["lib/libboost_wserialization.a"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

`./app/BUILD`:

```cxx
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")

cc_binary(
    name = "boost-log-test",
    srcs = ["log_test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@boost//:boost-headers",
        "@boost//:boost-log_setup",
        "@boost//:boost-log",
    ],
)
```

`./app/log_test.cpp` (exact copy of `/opt/boost/boost_1_77_0/libs/log/example/trivial/main.cpp`):

```cxx
/*
 *          Copyright Andrey Semashev 2007 - 2015.
 * Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
 *    (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
 *          http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 */
/*!
 * \file   main.cpp
 * \author Andrey Semashev
 * \date   07.11.2009
 *
 * \brief  An example of trivial logging.
 */

// #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK 1
// #define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1

#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Trivial logging: all log records are written into a file
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    // Filtering can also be applied
    using namespace boost::log;

    core::get()->set_filter
    (
        trivial::severity >= trivial::info
    );

    // Now the first two lines will not pass the filter
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

Build output:

```bash
[user@computer cpp]$ bazel build --cxxopt="-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK" --cxxopt="-lboost_log" --cxxopt="-lpthread" --cxxopt="-std=c++17" //app:boost-log-test
INFO: Analyzed target //app:boost-log-test (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/blueder/Projects/MarketProphet/cpp/app/BUILD:11:10: Linking app/boost-log-test failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc @bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/boost-log-test-2.params

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::get()'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::set_filter(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::filter const&)'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::lock_shared(): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::unlock_shared(): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_unlock'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name::attribute_name(char const*): error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const*)'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record::reset(): error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*)'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::severity<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> > >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> > >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> > const&): error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::get_logging_enabled() const'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record&): error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record&)'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::auto_release::~auto_release(): error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*)'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>::set_value(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level): error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> > >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument_list_of_1<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> > const&): error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::open_record(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_set const&)'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::push_record_unlocked(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record&&): error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record&)'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name) const'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::end() const'
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/app/_objs/boost-log-test/log_test.pic.o:log_test.cpp:function boost::log::v2_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(boost::exception&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Target //app:boost-log-test failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.175s, Critical Path: 0.04s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: You seem to be linking with a static library of Boost.Log while defining `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK`. See [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html).

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. I tried commenting out the `"@boost//:boost-log_setup",` and `"@boost//:boost-log",` and issuing `bazel build //app:boost-log-test` so that `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` was not invoked in the compilation process and got the same errors. Also note that it is commented out in the actual cpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `--cxxopt` options are passed to the compilation step not the link step, so anything of the form `--cxxopt=-lsomelib`. Use `--linkopts` to configure linking flags on the command line, or add, for example, `linkopts = ['-pthread']` to cc targets.
2. You may want to save yourself some effort and use the [preëxisting Bazel ruleset for Boost](https://github.com/nelhage/rules_boost).

Comment: Thanks for this, particularly the pre-existing Bazel ruleset for Boost. Not only is it building and running with Boost.Log correctly but it also handles getting the latest version of Boost for me without needing to install it myself.